# Angular6: Problems displaying images embedded in a page when using innerHTML?

Tags: angular

Can anyone help me with a project I'm working on in Angular 6. Its a basic blog application and my plan was to store the blog as html in a database and then retrieve it, sanitize it and then display it in an  HTML div element by using property binding to the innerHTML attribute. Below are the relevant sections of code I'm using.

HTML

```
post.postBody="<img src="../../../content/myimage.png" height='42' width='42'>";
```

Template

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" [innerHTML]="transformHTML(post.postBody)"></div>
</div>
```

Transform Method

```
transformHTML(html) {
  return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
}
```

The problem is that the image gets renamed from myimage.jpg to a30deb26b4eb1521433021e326cbcc2c.jpg, and since I'm using innerHTML Angular won't convert it as it would if the `<img>` tag was used directly in the template.

Any ideas how to get around this problem or an alternate stratergy? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just so I understand, after sanitizing the HTML, the angular sanitizer re-names the image to that convoluted alphanumeric string?? Or is something else doing the renaming?

Comment: Its not the santizer, after santizing the HTML the image name stays as 'myimage.jpg'. I'm using Angular to build the client and Spring Boot for the service layer using a generator called JHipster. The Angular app gets built using webpack and then the whole application gets packaged up into an executable jar using gradle. Somewhere during this process the actual image itself gets renamed, most likely for caching purposes.

Comment: I think you answered yourself - the image gets renamed in the build process. Remove the renaming from the build process and you should be fine...

Comment: @kvetis I think you're right. Had a re-think and if I want to set up a feature to add posts dynamically I also need to a facility to upload files for those posts anyway. Developing a feature to do this means I can control the file names hence problem solved. Thanks for your help guys.